# Detect and adjust width and height of images in dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some HTML that comes from a REST API. In that, I have a lot of  tags that may or may not have a width and height property set. The units don't come in "px", but just as a number.

```
<img class="embedded-image" src="http://example.com/img.svg" height="150" 
width="200">

<img class="embedded-image" src="http://example.com/img.svg" height="150">

<img class="embedded-image" src="http://example.com/img.svg" width="200">

<img class="embedded-image" src="http://example.com/img.svg">
```

Using CSS or JavaScript, I would like target these "img" tags and apply width property with px if it's set and set the height property if it's set. If none of them are set, we just leave as is.

Comment: *The units don't come in "px", but just as a number.* it's considered as pixel, you don't have to do anything. .... *The intrinsic height of the image, in pixels. Must be an integer without a unit.* (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already added them to the DOM, you can loop through and just see if the width and height exist.

```js
var _imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".embedded-image");
_imgs.forEach(function(el){
  if(el.getAttribute("height") != null){
    el.style.height = el.getAttribute("height") + "px";
  }
  
  if(el.getAttribute("width") != null){
    el.style.width = el.getAttribute("width") + "px";
  }
});
```

```html
<img class="embedded-image" src="http://example.com/img.svg" height="150" 
width="200">

<img class="embedded-image" src="http://example.com/img.svg" height="150">

<img class="embedded-image" src="http://example.com/img.svg" width="200">

<img class="embedded-image" src="http://example.com/img.svg">
```

Comment: hmm.. I am getting an error "Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'"